Error: org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;II)V
enter code hereI'm not sure what this error means or how to resolve it. Can someone please explain what might be causing this error and suggest how to fix it? I've checked my Hibernate configuration and mappings, but I haven't been able to find any issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
<springframework.security.version>5.6.12</springframework.security.version>
        <spring.version>5.3.29</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate.validator>5.4.1.Final</hibernate.validator>


    pom.xml  :                                                                                        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <!-- Every module inherits from its ROOT project -->
        <parent>
            <!-- Parent groupId -->
            <groupId>com.inetpsa.auk00</groupId>
            <artifactId>root</artifactId>
            <!-- Parent version to update -->
            <version>2.1.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <relativePath>../auk00Root</relativePath>
        </parent>
        <!-- Module identifier (WAR generated name) -->
        <artifactId>auk00Web</artifactId>
        <!-- Web project is a "war" -->
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <!-- TO EDIT: module name -->
        <name>auk00 WEB project</name>
        <!-- TO EDIT: a short description of your application -->
        <description>Web client of auk00 application</description>
        <build>
            <!-- TO EDIT: Java sources directory -->
            <sourceDirectory>JavaSource</sourceDirectory>
            <testSourceDirectory>test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    
            <!-- Resources to be included in the JAR in order of importance -->
            <resources>
                <!-- TO EDIT: resources paths to add to WEB-INF/classes, default configuration: -->
                <resource>
                    <directory>JavaSource</directory>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </resource>
            </resources>
            <testResources>
                <testResource>
                    <directory>test/resources</directory>
                </testResource>
            </testResources>
    
            <!-- For unit test classes and resources, refer to Java project -->
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>initialize</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>write-project-properties</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputFile>test/resources/.project.properties</outputFile>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Web directory containing for example JSP, fwkWebContext.xml, etc. -->
                        <warSourceDirectory>${webContent}</warSourceDirectory>
                        <!-- TO EDIT : It is possible to filter some Web resources -->
                        <webResources>
                            <!-- <resource> <directory> ${basedir}/filteredResources </directory> 
                                <filtering>true</filtering> </resource> -->
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!-- TO EDIT: plugin to set-up to deploy a WAR on a Development application 
                    server -->
                <!-- INFORMATION: only possible with Sun One and GlassFish, to deploy 
                    an EAR that is the recommendation, refer to EAR project's pom and delete 
                    this config. -->
                <!-- http://jip.inetpsa.com/en/plugins/maven-deployer-plugin/utilisation/configurerPom.html -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.inetpsa.jip.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-deployer-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <hostName>YVAL7340</hostName>
                        <connectionType>SSH</connectionType>
                        <userName>mdeauk00</userName>
                        <userHome>/users/auk00/tom90</userHome>
                        <!--  Crypted password key in security/passwords.crypt -->
                        <passwordName>yval7340.mdeauk00</passwordName>
                        <logFolder>/usersdev/anstat/log</logFolder>
                        <ftpConnectionType>SFTP</ftpConnectionType>
                        <applicationName>auk00Web</applicationName>
                        <archivePathOnServer>/users/auk00/tom90/installableApps/auk00Web.war</archivePathOnServer>
                        <prd>auk</prd>
                        <occ>00</occ>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
            <outputDirectory>${webContent}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        </build>
        <properties>
            <!-- Web directory containing for example JSP, fwkWebContext.xml, etc. -->
            <webContent>${basedir}/WebContent</webContent>
            <!-- DO NOT EDIT -->
            <webInfLibPath>${webContent}/WEB-INF/lib</webInfLibPath>
            <!-- TO EDIT: Subversion connection information, to delete if you use CVS -->
            <svnModuleName>auk00Web</svnModuleName>
            <oracle.server>yvai0160</oracle.server>
            <oracle.database>KRLDTS41</oracle.database>
            <oracle.port>1521</oracle.port>
            <oracle.url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@${oracle.server}:${oracle.port}:${oracle.database}</oracle.url>
            <oracle.user>OPS$EKIPKRL</oracle.user>
            <oracle.password>ekipkrldts01</oracle.password>
            <db.driver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</db.driver>
              <servlets.version>3.1.0</servlets.version>
            <jsp.version>2.3.1</jsp.version>
            <springframework.security.version>5.6.12</springframework.security.version>
            <spring.version>5.3.29</spring.version>
            <hibernate.version>5.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
            <hibernate.validator>5.4.1.Final</hibernate.validator>         
        </properties>
        <!-- TO EDIT: project dependencies -->
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>auk00ServiceGui</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
                <dependency>
                <groupId>com.inetpsa.sfj00</groupId>
                <artifactId>sfj00Web</artifactId>
                <version>${versionSFJ}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.inetpsa.sfj00</groupId>
                <artifactId>sfj00Web</artifactId>
                <version>${versionSFJ}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
                        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
                        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>struts2-bootstrap-plugin</artifactId>
                        <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.bootstrap</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.github.umeshawasthi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>struts2-jsr303-validation-plugin</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet Dependency -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>${servlets.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
              <!-- JSP Dependency -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>${jsp.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- REST -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
                <version>${jerseySpringVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
                <version>${jerseySpringVersion}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
                <version>${jerseySpringVersion}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>               
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-mvc</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>angularjs</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>3.7</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
                <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.22</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.2</version>
            </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId> 
        <version>${spring.version}</version> 
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
    <!-- spring security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    
         <!-- Hibernate Core -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.17.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Hibernate Validator -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.validator}</version>
            </dependency>
    
    
            <!-- Log dependencies -->
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging -->
          
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.11</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-jcl</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.11</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <version>4.12</version>
            </dependency>
         
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>oracle.jdbc-driver</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                <version>11.2.0.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
    
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.inetpsa.auk00</groupId>
                <artifactId>auk00Business</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project> 


applicationContext.xml :                                                                            
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"     
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"     
xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-5.6.xsd     http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd     http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws 
http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd" 
xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"    default-autowire="no">                                                                          <
!-- Datasource access by JNDI -->                                                          
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">       
<property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/auk00ds" />                             
</bean>                                                                                     
<bean id="mySessionFactory"         class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">                     
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />                                                   
<property name="packagesToScan" value="net.javaguides.springmvc.entity"/>       
<property name="configLocations">                                               
<list><value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value></list> </property></bean>                   
 <bean      class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />      
 <bean id="myTxManager"         class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">         
 <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" /> </bean>                  
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTxManager" />                                    
 <!--auk definition -->                                                                         
 <!--<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:auk.properties" /> -->               
 <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">         
 <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache" />     </bean>                                  
 <bean id="ehcache"         class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">                
 <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml" />                        
 </bean>                                                                                 
 <bean id="dozerBeanMapper" class="org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper">                          
 <property name="mappingFiles">     <list> </list> </property> </bean>                                  
 <!-- * * ANNOTATION CONFIGURATION * -->                                                            
 <!-- <cache:annotation-driven /> -->                                                       
 <context:annotation-config />                                                                                        
 <!-- * * ANNOTATION CONFIGURATION * -->                                                      
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.inetpsa" />                                                  
 <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />                                            
 <!-- Security configuration -->                                                                                        
 <!--   <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">                                     
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />                                  
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('MONITOR', 'UPLOAD')" />       
 <security:http-basic />                                                                           
 </security:http>-->                                                                                                    
 <security:authentication-manager id="secuManager">                                         
 <security:authentication-provider ref="sfjBasicLdapAuthenticationProvider" />                                             
 </security:authentication-manager>     <bean id="jacksonMessageConverter"      
 class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />     
 <bean  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter">      
 <property name="messageConverters">                                                                                                
 <list>                                                                                                   
 <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter" />                                                                    
 </list>                                                                                              
 </property>                                                                                                 
 </bean>                                                                                                    
 <!-- freemarker config -->                                                                                      
 <bean id="freemarkerConfig"        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">       
 <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WebContent/" />                                                         
 </bean>                                                                                                       
 <!-- View resolver -->                                                                                
 <bean id="viewResolver"        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">         
 <property name="cache" value="true" />                                                                       
 <property name="prefix" value="" />                                                                       
 <property name="suffix" value=".html" />                                                                      
 </bean>                                                                                                
 <bean id="multipartResolver"       class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />                                  
 <!--    <bean id="webexpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler" ></bean> -->         
 <!-- no filter for resource folders -->                                                              
 <security:http pattern="/images/**" security="none" />                                                                             
 <security:http pattern="/css/**" security="none"  />                                                                   
 <security:http pattern="/script/arrearsnotices/**" security="none" />                                                           
 <security:http pattern="/scripom.xmlt/**" security="none" />                                               
 <security:http pattern="/fonts/**" security="none" />                                                                                                                                                             
 </beans> 

hibernate.cfg.xml :                                                                                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">false</property>
        
                <mapping class="com.inetpsa.sfj.db.model.ldapauth.Authority" />
        <mapping class="com.inetpsa.sfj.db.model.ldapauth.BasicProfileAuth" />
        <mapping class="com.inetpsa.sfj.db.model.ldapauth.Profile" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>



I'm not sure what this error means or how to resolve it. Can someone please explain what might be causing this error and suggest how to fix it? I've checked my Hibernate configuration and mappings, but I haven't been able to find any issues.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Please add your complete log that will help to understand

hello i added the complete log please help me !!
